# How to convert List of arrays to two dimensional array?

Tags: visual-c++, collections, c++-cli

I have a list of arrays where I added many arrays but all of them are the same size. Now I want convert this list to two dimensional array. I tried in this way:

```
List<Array^>^ vList = gcnew List<Array^>();
//some code where I add elements to vList
array<String ^, 2> ^ anArray = gcnew array<String ^, 2>(vList->Count, 5);
anArray = vList->ToArray();
```

But I have got this error:

```
a value of type "cli::array<System::Array ^, 1> ^" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "cli::array<System::String ^, 2> ^"
```

I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: Do pick the right types, fall in the pit of success with a `List<array<String>^>^` so you nail down the element type and don't have to deal with the misery of having an array element that is not a string.  And a jagged array instead of a 2-dimensional array (array<array<String^>^>^) so ToArray() can work.  Lots faster too.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. `cli::array<System::Array^>^ tablica2D;` works but it is not what I wanted and I can't get item with given index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to iterate and copy all of the strings individually. However, the raw type `Array^` isn't that convenient to work with, so you'll need to do something about that.

Basically, what you need to do is this:

```
for (int outer = 0; outer < vList->Count; outer++)
{
    arrayOfSomeSort^ innerArray = vList[outer];
    for (int inner = 0; inner < innerArray.Length; inner++)
        anArray[outer, inner] = innerArray[inner];
}
```

Depending on how the rest of the program is, and what objects are actually in the List, there are a few options on what to do. Here are the options I see, in order of preference.

1. Instead of a `List<Array^>^`, have `vList` be a `List<array<String^>^>^`. If the List truly is a list of string arrays, then this option is probably the most correct. In this case, `arrayOfSomeSort^` would be `array<String^>^`.
2. If `vList` can't change type, but it does indeed contain string arrays, then I'd have the local variable `innerArray` be of type `array<String^>^`, and do a cast as you pull it out of `vList`.
3. If the arrays in the list aren't string arrays, but instead are object arrays that happen to contain strings, then I'd have `array<Object^>^ innerArray`, and cast to that instead, and do a cast to `String^` as you pull each string out of `innerArray`.
4. If none of those is appropriate, then you can leave `innerArray` as type `Array^`. You'll need to call the explicit method [`Array.GetValue(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6swd8604.aspx) instead of using the `[]` indexer. As with the previous option, you'll need to cast each string as you pull it out of the inner array.

You've set the second dimension to 5 without checking the lengths of the inner arrays; I'm assuming you know something we don't, and are sure that there won't be anything larger than 5. If not, you'll need to iterate the list once to get the maximum array size, create the 2D array, and then copy the strings.

Comment: Yes, second dimension is 5 and it is hardcoded. I have a list of arrays with the same (=5) dimension. Unfortunately I get an error `a value of type "System::Object ^" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "System::String ^"` I tried also `anArray[outer, inner] = (String ^) innerArray[inner];`  but `'default': is not a member of 'System::Array'` error appears.

Comment: Bah, that's what I get for typing up an answer without checking it in a compiler. If the `Array^`s in the list are actually `array<String^>^`, then the best solution would be to switch the `List<Array^>^` to a `List<array<String^>^>^`. If that's not possible, then I'd do a cast of `innerArray` to `array<String^>^` when you pull it out of the list. If they're `array<Object^>^`, then cast to that instead, and cast the individual elements to `String^`, as you tried. If neither of those work, then you can call the GetValue(int) method on the `Array^`, and cast/convert the result to `String^`.